# Does a separate thread need it's own VersionControlServer instance to work simultaneously with another?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

Suppose there are an arbitrary number of threads in my C# program. Each thread needs to look up the changeset ids for a particular path by looking up it's history. The method looks like so:

```cs
public List<int> GetIdsFromHistory(string path, VersionControlServer tfsClient)
{ 
   IEnumerable submissions = tfsClient.QueryHistory(
      path,
      VersionSpec.Latest,
      0,
      RecursionType.None, // Assume that the path is to a file, not a directory
      null,
      null,
      null,
      Int32.MaxValue,
      false,
      false);

   List<int> ids = new List<int>();
   foreach(Changeset cs in submissions)
   {
      ids.Add(cs.ChangesetId);
   }
   return ids;
}
```

My question is, does each thread need it's own `VersionControlServer` instance or will one suffice? My intuition tells me that each thread needs its own instance since the TFS SDK uses webservices and I should probably have more than one connection open if I'm really going to get the parallel behavior. If I only use one connection, my intuition tells me that I'll get serial behavior even though I've got multiple threads.

If I need as many instances as there are threads, I think of using an Object-Pool pattern, but will the connections time out and close over a long period if not being used? The docs seem sparse in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that threads using the SAME client is the fastest option.

Here's the output from a test program that runs 4 tests 5 times each and returns the average result in milliseconds. Clearly using the same client across multiple threads is the fastest execution:

```
Parallel Pre-Alloc: Execution Time Average (ms): 1921.26044
Parallel AllocOnDemand: Execution Time Average (ms): 1391.665
Parallel-SameClient: Execution Time Average (ms): 400.5484
Serial: Execution Time Average (ms): 1472.76138
```

For reference, here's the test program itself (also on [GitHub](https://github.com/mrcaron/Tfs2010QueryHistoryPerfExp/commits/master/QueryHistoryPerformanceTesting/Program.cs)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace QueryHistoryPerformanceTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static string TFS_COLLECTION = /* TFS COLLECTION URL */
        static VersionControlServer GetTfsClient()
        {
            var projectCollectionUri = new Uri(TFS_COLLECTION);
            var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri, new UICredentialsProvider());
            projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
            return projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        }

        struct ThrArg
        {
            public VersionControlServer tfc { get; set; }
            public string path { get; set; }
        }

        static List<string> PATHS = new List<string> {
            // ASSUME 21 FILE PATHS
        };

        static int NUM_RUNS = 5;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = new List<TimeSpan>();

            for (int i = NUM_RUNS; i > 0; i--)
            {
                results.Add(RunTestParallelPreAlloc());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel Pre-Alloc: Execution Time Average (ms): " + results.Select(t => t.TotalMilliseconds).Average());

            results.Clear();
            for (int i = NUM_RUNS; i > 0; i--)
            {
                results.Add(RunTestParallelAllocOnDemand());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel AllocOnDemand: Execution Time Average (ms): " + results.Select(t => t.TotalMilliseconds).Average());

            results.Clear();
            for (int i = NUM_RUNS; i > 0; i--)
            {
                results.Add(RunTestParallelSameClient());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel-SameClient: Execution Time Average (ms): " + results.Select(t => t.TotalMilliseconds).Average());

            results.Clear();
            for (int i = NUM_RUNS; i > 0; i--)
            {
                results.Add(RunTestSerial());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Serial: Execution Time Average (ms): " + results.Select(t => t.TotalMilliseconds).Average());
        }

        static TimeSpan RunTestParallelPreAlloc()
        {
            var paths = new List<ThrArg>();
            paths.AddRange( PATHS.Select( x => new ThrArg { path = x, tfc = GetTfsClient() } ) );
            return RunTestParallel(paths);
        }

        static TimeSpan RunTestParallelAllocOnDemand()
        {
            var paths = new List<ThrArg>();
            paths.AddRange(PATHS.Select(x => new ThrArg { path = x, tfc = null }));
            return RunTestParallel(paths);
        }

        static TimeSpan RunTestParallelSameClient()
        {
            var paths = new List<ThrArg>();
            var _tfc = GetTfsClient();
            paths.AddRange(PATHS.Select(x => new ThrArg { path = x, tfc = _tfc }));
            return RunTestParallel(paths);
        }

        static TimeSpan RunTestParallel(List<ThrArg> args)
        {
            var allIds = new List<int>();

            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            Parallel.ForEach(args, s =>
            {
                allIds.AddRange(GetIdsFromHistory(s.path, s.tfc));
            }
            );
            stopWatch.Stop();

            return stopWatch.Elapsed;
        }

        static TimeSpan RunTestSerial()
        {
            var allIds = new List<int>();
            VersionControlServer tfsc = GetTfsClient();

            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            foreach (string s in PATHS)
            {
                allIds.AddRange(GetIdsFromHistory(s, tfsc));
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();

            return stopWatch.Elapsed;
        }

        static List<int> GetIdsFromHistory(string path, VersionControlServer tfsClient)
        {
            if (tfsClient == null)
            {
                tfsClient = GetTfsClient();
            }

            IEnumerable submissions = tfsClient.QueryHistory(
                path,
                VersionSpec.Latest,
                0,
                RecursionType.None, // Assume that the path is to a file, not a directory
                null,
                null,
                null,
                Int32.MaxValue,
                false,
                false);

            List<int> ids = new List<int>();
            foreach(Changeset cs in submissions)
            {
                ids.Add(cs.ChangesetId);
            }
            return ids;
        }
```

Comment: As a side note, I also [implemented the above using a delegate](https://github.com/mrcaron/Tfs2010QueryHistoryPerfExp/blob/master/QueryHistoryPerformanceTesting/Program.cs), but it threw the result times WAY off (no idea why tho): `Parallel Pre-Alloc: Execution Time Average (ms): 5418.07828; Parallel Alloc OnDemand: Execution Time Average (ms): 1312.86686; Parallel SameClient: Execution Time Average (ms): 370.89382; Serial: Execution Time Average (ms): 288.3632`